# How to get onClick state?

Tags: android, onclick

I have an ImageView which I have set `android:clickable="true"` and I use the `setColorFilter()` to add a color when the ImageView is clicked.

Is there a way I can get the state of the `onClick()` so that when the image is clicked once I can apply the color, for example `setColorFilter(#FFF)`, and when the ImageView is clicked again I apply `setColorFilter(null)` to return the ImageView to normal?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
boolean flag=false;

imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (flag) {
                    imageView.setColorFilter(null);
                }
                else {
                    imageView.setColorFilter(yourColor);
                }
                flag=!flag;
            }
        });
```

This way is so simple for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a code with increasing the value of a counter, which then you can see, is odd or even and do your stuff.

What I am saying, look something like this in code:

```java
int clicked = 0;

buttonX.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v){
       if(clicked%2 == 0){
          // apply colour and do your stuff
       }
       else{
          clickedOnce++;

       }

    } 
});
```

This would get your work done, alternate times, when you click the button. You can also set this `clicked` to zero once again, when the activity is left or something like that, to avoid getting `clicked` value increasing too much.

Answer (score 0):

The usual practice in these cases is to store such kind of info about the state of the View in its tag:

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) view; 
        String tag = iv.getTag() == null ? "0" : iv.getTag().toString();
        if (tag.equals("1")) {
            iv.setColorFilter(null);
            iv.setTag("0");
        } else {
            iv.setColorFilter(yourColor);
            iv.setTag("1");
        }
    }
});
```

The listener toggles the tag of the `ImageView` from `"0"` to `"1"` each time it's clicked.